# Spring MVC resolving error code

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am creating a login form in Spring MVC. My spring version is 4.0.6.
I have configured my properties file ApplicationResources.properties like below

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:ApplicationResources</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am able to read value of lables defined in property file by using tag lib like below

```
<spring:message code="ui.label.username" />
```

But I am facing problem with validation below is the controller class method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doLogin.spr" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    try{
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("command", loginForm);
            return "login" ;
        }
        User user = loginService.login(loginForm.getUserName(), loginForm.getPassword());
        return "login" ;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception       
        return "login" ;
    }

}
```

In my validator I am validating field like below

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName", "app.ui.userName.error");
```

In my property file I have defined labels like below.

```
app.ui.userName.error.loginForm.userName=First UserName
app.ui.userName.error.userName=Second UserName
app.ui.userName.error.java.lang.String=String UserName
app.ui.userName.error=Simple error
```

On JSP I am trying to access error like below

```
 <form:errors path="userName"/>
```

But I am not able to see error message on my UI. What could be problem here.

Comment: Is the <form:errors/> tag enclosed within your form?

Comment: Yes it is inside in form tag

Comment: I think problem is with resolving the errorcode with message

Comment: It worked by changing my model name from command to loginform.